# How do I change which mirror I get updates and software from?

Tags: software-sources, mirrors

How do I select which server Ubuntu will get it's software and updates from? I know how to find the [list of mirrors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9408/how-can-i-find-an-always-updated-list-of-repository-mirrors) on the web, but not how to use them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quite easy:

- Open the *Software & Updates* (you can also start this using the `software-properties-gtk` command)
- Find the *Download From* dropdown and select *Other*

  [image]
- Choose the server you want:

  [image]

  If you click *Select Best Server*, the USC will go through a load of tests to find the server that's fastest in your location. Generally it will be a server close by.
- For a lot more information on this, see the [Ubuntu Community Documentation on Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)