# Software is not installing

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install a software(texmaker). I am getting the error "Failed to download package files Check your Internet connection."

My Internet connection is working

Comment: Where are you downloading/trying to download from? Have you tried http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily change the mirror you download the packages from:

1. Open the *System Settings* from the Session Indicator (this icon in the top right corner in Unity: [image])
2. Run *Software Sources*
3. Choose *Main Server* from the *Download From* drop-down box.

   - [How do I change which mirror I get updates and software from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from)