# Stopping upgrade to 12.04 during "Getting new packages" phase?

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are updates downloading so slow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124631/why-are-updates-downloading-so-slow)

I'm currently in the middle of the "Getting new packages" phase of my 11.10 to 12.04 LTS upgrade. It's going slower than expected and I need to leave soon, taking my laptop with me. If I press cancel the operation, will it remove all upgrade progress, necessitating that I start from the beginning again? Or will it resume from the progress at the time of cancelling?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how this question is an exact duplicate. Mine asks what the results will be of cancelling an operation and the other asks why downloads are slow.