# Installation process takes too long

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are updates downloading so slow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124631/why-are-updates-downloading-so-slow)

When I was installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my system the installation process stopped at 43 of 93. There it spent about 1 hour, but did not proceed, so then I skipped the process.

After that, installation process ended successfully. The same problem occured when i installed Ubuntu 10.10 as well as Ubuntu 11.04 in my system.

Though I can't see any major problems, I want to know if there could be any minor/major problem that I haven't noticed.

Is there any file or application that would have been prevented from installing and how can I sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're installing from a CD and you have not checked the case : "install updates from internet".
If you do, then it might be that connection is a bit slow.

If You don't, there is an arrow next to the progress bar that you can click on, the pieces of informations written there (in a terminal like) could have help us tell you what's taking so long.