# Installation has stalled

Tags: installation

New installation on desktop has got to 'Downloading packages' but seems to have stalled; continues to show numbers - e.g. (216:58 remaining) - which constantly change, but progress bar has stopped; been running for at least 9 hours.

Answer (score 0):

#### New installation:

Sometimes, especially around new releases we are faced with servers having issues to provide the data in time. In this case, or when we have a slow internet connection locally it may be better to run the installation from CD or USB. We should not download updates or additional packages during the installation process in this case. After the installation is complete we can then update our system, where we may choose a [different mirror](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from) to do so.

#### Upgrade from a previous installation:

On some occasions we need user action outside the GUI-window of the installer during an upgrade. Debconf may have asked you to press a key. To see this we need to click on *Details* in the installer window.

See also the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop):

> In some cases update-manager might appear to hang indefinitely. In that case, open the expander at the bottom and check if there is a debconf question which needs to be answered. ([979661](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/979661))