# My apt-get update is taking too much and finally error?

Tags: apt, software-center, update-manager, software-sources

I was trying apt-get update but from an over night wait i found this !!
[image: I use guake and i was updating but...]

[image: My software source , is that what i have to change or recommended ? will you recommend the saoftware source setting ?]

[image: Please recommend me the settings of software source]

[image: Plz.]

Also my software centre is showing , when i click some software to install it shows it is from multiverse source or something and when i click to "use the source" it shows updating catch and goes and goes and actually no data transfer use....????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update should be using your chosen Malaysian mirror, NOT `us.archive.ubuntu.com` (US default mirror).

Open Software Center from the launcher (looks like a shopping bag), or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `software-center`, press enter. Go into Software Sources and make sure it is set to a Malaysian mirror (enter your password when prompted). Then try updating again.

---

Linked Question:

- [How do I change which mirror I get updates and software from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from)

Comment: Ok done....but showing this "Reading package lists... Done
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 8CD60EC948894010 Launchpad PPA for Scopes Packagers

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/scopes-packagers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa -y; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-add-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa -y; apt-get update` to fix that...