# 12.04 apt-get update taking long time. How to speed up?

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

sudo apt-get update is taking long time for following sites:

```
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]                                                                                                               
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB]  
...
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [8,431 B]                                                                                                         
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4,796 kB]
```

Anyway to speed up this? Internet connection is good.

Comment: There is a current issue with canonical's servers (http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11952584&postcount=24) causing slow downloads

Comment: For the most part the London server issues have been resolved, speeds when using the the 'Main' or 'US' servers should be back or close to normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources` and from `Download From` drop down menu choose `Other` then on the next window choose `Select Best Server` and wait to ubuntu recognize best server for you, then run `apt-get update` again...

---

Linked Question:
 - [How do I change which mirror I get updates and software from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete more than ppas.
You can try the following command: sudo apt-get clean.
With Ubuntu Tweak, delete unnecessary files on the system.

Answer (score 0):

This is command-line oriented answer (especially useful for speeding up provisioning VMs).

If you added new repository recently and you want to update partially, try:

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name '*.list' -exec sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="{}" ';'
```

It won't work in all cases (in case of more complex dependencies), but it's worth a try.

You can also try `-d` to download packages only. See: [What does "sudo apt-get update" do?](https://askubuntu.com/q/222348/78223)

Alternatively remove lines from apt list files which you don't need, e.g.:

```
sudo ex +'bufdo!%s/^deb-src/#deb-src/' -scxa /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-*.list
```

which will comment out lines pointing to sources in those files.

<sup>Note: The `:bufdo` command is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).</sup>

Check also if you don't have any useless scripts in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, e.g.:

```
sudo ex +"%s@DPkg@//DPkg" -scwq /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

See:[Disable prompts while installing a Debian package](https://serverfault.com/q/210948/130437) at SF

Comment: note bufdo is not POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html