# How do I fetch from another mirror?

Tags: repository, mirrors, exfat

I've come around some broken repositories. How do I change the mirror for this apt-get only??
I am using ubuntu server 12.04.

```
    alex@****:~$ sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
    [sudo] password for alex: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      exfat-fuse exfat-utils
    0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
    Need to get 130 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 329 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Err http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports/universe exfat-fuse i386 1.0.1-1~ubuntu12.04.1
      Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
    Err http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports/universe exfat-utils i386 1.0.1-1~ubuntu12.04.1
      Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
    Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fuse-exfat/exfat-fuse_1.0.1-1~ubuntu12.04.1_i386.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
    Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/exfat-utils/exfat-utils_1.0.1-1~ubuntu12.04.1_i386.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
    alex@****:~$ su
    Password: 
    root@****:/home/alex# sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb /mnt/extdisk/
    mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Comment: The easiest option is just to change the mirror, and then change back later when the problem is resolved.

Comment: How do I change it?? just editing the sources.list file will be enough? In my case editing all "pl" to let say "us"??

Comment: Yes, replace all of the mirror locations and make sure to do `apt-get update` first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change which mirror I get updates and software from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from)