# ubuntu 12.04 update manager failure, error 404

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

I keep getting a very ominous looking red exclamation point telling me to manually check for updates as the package info is outdated, but when I attempt to do so I get an error saying there was a `failure to download repository information`. When I click "details" I get this message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80] , 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried a few different things but nothing has worked as of yet. I've got Ubuntu 12.04 and it's a 32-bit. any ideas?

Comment: try another mirror

Comment: i actually don't know about mirrors. this is actually the 1st time i've really tried to figure out and resolve this sort of issue. i'm what you'd call a novice, so if you could explain?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from

Comment: If that does not work, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: ok i think that worked, at least now it seems to be updating ok. you're a genius, bodhi.zazen, thanks a ton.

Comment: It is a common problem , mirrors can be down for a variety of reasons. In this event, simply use an alternate.