# Error while updating the Ubuntu Repositories etc

Tags: 14.04, updates, repository

I have experienced this kind of error ever since it had a server error. Can someone explain me to this and help me resolve this problem? Thanks!

Error on updating Ubuntu: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: If it's a server error, you can't do much. Pick a different one:  [How do I change which mirror I get updates and software from?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from)

Comment: Okay sir.. I'll try other repositories for it. :)

Comment: Change the mirror - *ph* is probably for Philippines, try *jp* or *kr* for instance.