# i want to convert Ubuntu to Xubuntu but I get this problem

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, dpkg, dependencies

Using this command apt-get install xubuntu-desktop i get this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
```

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
xubuntu-desktop : Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: xubuntu-artwork but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: xubuntu-default-settings but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: bluez-cups but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: cups
               Recommends: gmusicbrowser but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-system-tools but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: hplip but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: pidgin but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: printer-driver-splix but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: xchat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors reported are due to you not having the Universe repository enabled in your software sources.

Fortunately we have a great Q&A that covers this in detail - I'm not going to repeat the same info here:

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

After enabling the universe repository, re-run the update process:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Try the answer here ... If it works I'll mark this as a duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: i try that before i post the question and it doesn't work

Comment: Try changing your mirror ... Possibly there are missing packages in your current mirror repository ... http://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from