# Problem install texlive-xetex

Tags: apt, package-management, latex, texlive

After running

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```

I get

```
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 texlive-fonts-recommended all 2017.20180305-1                                                             
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 texlive-fonts-recommended all 2017.20180305-1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/texlive-base/texlive-fonts-recommended_2017.20180305-1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Aborting install.
```

Why is this happening & how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

First, run `sudo apt update` and retry installing `texlive-xetex`.

If that does not work, [switch to a different mirror](https://askubuntu.com/a/53087/124466).