# apt-get update on kubuntu doesn't work

Tags: apt

When I execute the command `sudo apt-get update` on kubuntu 18.04 It outputs:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                 
Err:3 http://(Country code).archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                  
  Could not connect to (Country code).archive.ubuntu.com:80 (212.43.0.68), connection timed out
Err:4 http://(Country Code).archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to (Country code).archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:5 http://(County code).archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to (Country code).archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Fetched 88.7 kB in 30s (2,916 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://(Country code).archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to (Country code).archive.ubuntu.com:80 (212.43.0.68), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://(Country code).archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to (Country code).archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://(Country code0.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to (Country code).archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please help, As I cannot install most of the things I need this way. (user535733's Last comment fixed the problem, thanks)

Comment: Try a different mirror. "*connection timed out*" looks like a networking problem perhaps unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry but I just installed kubuntu (1st time using any linux laptop)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/53084/how-do-i-change-which-mirror-i-get-updates-and-software-from for how to try a different mirror. Tip: Use the Search box at the top of the page for fast answers.

Comment: I guess there is no "Software & Updates" in Kubuntu

Comment: Of course there is. Keep looking...or open a terminal and run `software-properties-qt`

Comment: Command not found...

Comment: Well, then I suppose you must not have it. That's unusual, since it's part of every stock Kubuntu install. You must look up how to edit a text file (using `nano` is easiest). Then edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list to change the country code in each URL. Since that's a root-owned file, you must use `sudo` when you launch the editor. That's a lot to bite off for a beginner, though the actual changes are quite easy.

Comment: user535733's Last comment fixed the problem, How do I make it the answer?