apt update times out
Quite new to Linux, I've just spin up an instance of Ubuntu 22.04 Linux Server on IBM (using $200 free credit). And I'm pretty sure it used to work when I tried that earlier on other Linux machines, but for the last few hours this is what I've been getting when I run apt update
Ign:1 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:1 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to mirrors.service.networklayer.com:80 (10.0.77.54), connection timed out
Err:2 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to mirrors.service.networklayer.com:http:
Err:3 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to mirrors.service.networklayer.com:http:
Err:4 http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to mirrors.service.networklayer.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not connect to mirrors.service.networklayer.com:80 (10.0.77.54), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to mirrors.service.networklayer.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to mirrors.service.networklayer.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Unable to connect to mirrors.service.networklayer.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@virtualserver01:~#

This is the first command I run after connecting to it via ssh. So far I tried initiating an instance of Linux on other IBM regions and still getting the same result. Nothing gets downloaded because when I run apt upgrade I get 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. I'm pretty sure it's connected to the internet because it's able to ping Google's IP address

Try a different mirror.

Is there any guide on how to do that? Quite a lot of guides out there not sure which one to look at.

Many questions have been asked already. Try searching the site. Here's what came up in a search for "different mirror" https://askubuntu.com/q/53084/243321
